# Variáveis retornando trying to get object of non object

Tags: php

Todas as transições de tela, quando preciso chamar um dado variável, estão com esse problema. Sempre retorna o vetor como vazio.

Quanto as transições são feitas com valor definidos, como por exemplo: `$_POST ['vaga'] = ['2']`, o vetor é retornado com todas as suas variáveis `(40)` sem erro no formulário `html`.

Mas o problema é que o valor citado no exemplo `['2']` deve ser variável, pois ele deve ser atribuído de outra lista. A relação é:

*página 1* - lista de vagas com 5 variáveis principais e 1 botão para apresentar os detalhes da vaga;

*página 2* - detalhes da vaga selecionada no botão da página 1;

O código que funciona, com a variável fixa é:

---

```
include_once('class_vaga.php');

$obj = new class_vaga();
$obj->host = '127.0.0.1';
$obj->username = 'root';
$obj->password = '';
$obj->table = 'vaga';
$obj->connect();


$_POST ['vaga'] = ['2'];

$return = json_decode($obj->ajaxCall('load_detalhes_vagas',array($_POST['vaga'][0])));

var_dump($return);

?>
```

---

Quando tento fazê-la variar de acordo com o botão clicado é que vem o problema. Reparei que isso ocorre em todas as outras páginas (login, gráficos, etc), pois sempre que uso um número fixo o sistema aceita, na hora de torná-lo variável a coisa trava.

**Código que não funciona:**

```
include_once('class_vaga.php');

$obj = new class_vaga();
$obj->host = '127.0.0.1';
$obj->username = 'root';
$obj->password = '';
$obj->table = 'vaga';
$obj->connect();

$id_vaga = ' ';

foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {

    if($key == "action"){
        $action = $value;
    }else{
            $id_vaga = $value;
    }
}

$return = json_decode($obj->ajaxCall('load_detalhes_vagas',array($id_vaga)));

var_dump($return);

?>
```

---

a função de chamada da página 2 é:

```
function loaddetalhes(idVaga){
       $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: 'http://localhost/workspace/detalhes_vaga.php',
                    data: { action: 'load_detalhes_vagas', vaga: idVaga },
                    dataType: "json",
                    complete: function (data){
                    window.open('detalhes_vaga.php');
                    },
                });
      }
```

---

Comment: olha no campo do hml se vc colocou o atributo name. Pois o problema está na passagem do parametro. adicione aqui o su codigo html do formulario 1 e te mostro onde está o problema

Comment: não consigo incluir o codigo aqui no comentário...falta espaço

Comment: <img src="imgs/plus.png" width="30" height="30" alt="Mais informaÃ§Ãµes" style="cursor:pointer" id="btnloaddetalhes" name="detalhesvaga" onclick="loaddetalhes('<?= $v->id_vaga; ?>');"></td>

Comment: edita sua pergunta e inclue o html

Answer (score 0):

Para descobrir o erro você precisa verificar se o parametro chega corretamente, com:

`var_dump($_POST);` antes do `foreach`, se vier a vaga significa que está passando a variável de forma correta. Ou se você achar melhor faça isso no javascript console.log(idVaga), antes do `$.ajax({` pelo console do browser você vai ver.

Para tratar vagas que não existem faça uma simples alteração no seu código, assim você desvia os erros.

Primeiro elimine seu foreach e mude para este código:

```
if(isset($_POST['vaga'],isset($_POST['action']) && $_POST['vaga'] && $_POST['action']){
     $json = json_decode($obj->ajaxCall($_POST['action'],$_POST['vagas']));
     var_dump($json);
}
```

Agora vamos as boas práticas, **elimine seu foreach**, trate tudo com **try catch** e troque a variável **$return** para outro nome, return é palavra reservada da PHP.

Ao menos os erros vão sumir, o erro tyr get non object, significa que ele está tentando buscar um objeto em uma variável nula ou não objeto.